# How to use an array of coordinates with Google Elevation API?

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to send several locations in one request to Google Elevation API, you are supposed to be able to send up to 512 locations per request. Their documentation says to use: 
An array of coordinates separated using the pipe ('|') character: locations=40.714728,-73.998672|-34.397,150.644
but I am getting back the error:
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 99: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=51.606013718523265,-8.432384161819547|51.606031961540985,-8.432374430210215|51.60607166348032,-8.432334651837888|51.60610446039263,-8.4322494395575&key=myAPIkey
It works if I just send a single point. I am told to use the pipe ('|') character yet it won't accept it. My code is

```
 position = ellipsePositions.get(index1);              
 longitude = position.getLongitude();
 latitude = position.getLatitude();
 APIstring = latitude + "," + longitude;

 for (int index = 1; index < indexList.size(); index++)
 {
    if (ellipsePositions.get(index) != null)
    { 
       position = ellipsePositions.get(index);              
       longitude = position.getLongitude();
       latitude = position.getLatitude();
       APIstring = APIstring + "|" +  latitude + "," + longitude;
    }
 }
```

and

```
WebResource webResource =   client.resource("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations="+ APIstring + "&key=myAPIkey");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
String data = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If I remove the (invalid) key from your [posted request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=51.606013718523265,-8.432384161819547|51.606031961540985,-8.432374430210215|51.60607166348032,-8.432334651837888|51.60610446039263,-8.43224943955), it works for me in a browser.  Did you investigate URL encoding the string?

Comment: Thank you, I replaced "|" with "%7C" and it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode any "unsafe" characters in the query string.  Per the [documentation on web services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs)

> **Building a Valid URL**
>
> You may think that a "valid" URL is self-evident, but that's not quite the case. A URL entered within an address bar in a browser, for example, may contain special characters (e.g. "上海+中國"); the browser needs to internally translate those characters into a different encoding before transmission. By the same token, any code that generates or accepts UTF-8 input might treat URLs with UTF-8 characters as "valid", but would also need to translate those characters before sending them out to a web server. This process is called URL-encoding.
>
> We need to translate special characters because all URLs need to conform to the syntax specified by the W3 Uniform Resource Identifier specification. In effect, this means that URLs must contain only a special subset of ASCII characters: the familiar alphanumeric symbols, and some reserved characters for use as control characters within URLs.
>
> Some common characters that must be encoded are:

```
Unsafe character   Encoded value
|                  %7C
```